# Matlab equivalent to Mathematica's FindInstance

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, solver

I do just about everything in Matlab but I have yet to work out a good way to replicate Mathematica's FindInstance function in Matlab. As an example, with Mathematica, I can enter:

```
FindInstance[x + y == 1 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}]
```

And it will give me:

```
{{x -> 1/2, y -> 1/2}}
```

When no solution exists, it will give me an empty Out. I use this often in my work to check whether or not a solution to a system of inequalities exists -- I don't really care about a particular solution.

It seems like there should be a way to replicate this in Matlab with [Solve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html). There are sections in the help file on solving a set of inequalities for a parametrized solution with conditions. There's another section on spitting out just one solution using PrincipalValue, but this seems to just select from a finite solution set, rather than coming up with one that meets the parameters.

Can anybody come up with a way to replicate the FindInstance functionality in Matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on what jlandercy said, you can certainly use MATLAB's [`linprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) function, which is MATLAB's linear programming solver.  A linear program in the MATLAB universe can be formulated like so:

[image]

You seek to find a solution `x` in `R^n` which minimizes the objective function `f^{T}*x` subject to a set of inequality constraints, equality constraints, and each component in `x` is bounded between a lower and upper bound.  Because you want to find the minimum possible value that satisfies the above constraint given, what you're really after is:

[image]

Because MATLAB only supports inequalities of less than, you'll need to take the negative of the first two constraints.  In addition, MATLAB doesn't support **strict** inequalities, and so what you'll have to do is enforce a constraint so that you are checking to see if each variable is lesser than a small number, perhaps something like setting a threshold `epsilon` to `1e-4`.  Therefore, with the above, your formulation is now:

[image]

Note that we don't have any upper or lower bounds as those conditions are already satisfied in the equality and inequality constraints.  All you have to do now is plug this problem into `linprog`.  `linprog` accepts syntax in the following way:

```
x = linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq);
```

`f` is a vector of coefficients that work with the objective function, `A` is a matrix of coefficients that work with the inequality, `b` is a vector of coefficients that are for the right-hand side of each inequality constraint, and `Aeq`,`beq`, are the same as the inequality but for the equality constraints.  `x` would be the solution to the linear programming problem formulated. If we reformulate your problem into matrix form for the above, we now get:

[image]

With respect to the linear programming formulation, we can now see what each variable in the MATLAB universe needs to be.  Therefore, in MATLAB syntax, each variable becomes:

```
f = [1; 1];
A = [-1 0; 0 -1];
b = [1e-4; 1e-4];
Aeq = [1 1];
beq = 1;
```

As such:

```
x = linprog(f, A, b, Aeq, beq);
```

We get:

```
Optimization terminated.

x =

    0.5000
    0.5000
```

---

If linear programming is not what you're looking for, consider looking at MATLAB's MuPAD interface: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/solve-algebraic-equations-and-inequalities.html - This more or less mimics what you see in Mathematica if you're more comfortable with that.

---

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I've been messing around with it for a few moments and this should be a relatively efficient way of doing it. Indeed, negating the constraints allows >=. As for strict inequalities, it's a little more complicated than just using eps. For instance, if you ask it to solve with constraints x+y<=1 and x+y>=1+eps, it will give x=y=1/2 because eps is smaller than the default tolerance on linprog (which actually varies across the algorithms it chooses between).  So I'm using 1e-4 for now instead.

Comment: Also, the Solve function to which I referred in the original question was one of those MuPAD features. I am aware of them -- my initial hope from this question was to get more specific guidance on how to use MuPAD/Solve to quickly test for the existence of solutions to a set of inequalities (some strict). From what little I've done with Solve, it looks like it might be slower than just doing it numerically with linprog anyway.

Comment: @Shane - That's true.  I forgot about the tolerances, so I'm glad you figured that out.  I better update my post to reflect this. In addition, using `linprog` on small systems such as the one you're dealing with... I would say that using `linprog` would be more efficient.  Thanks for your constructive comments, and glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Matlab is not a symbolic solver as Mathematica is, so you will not get exact solutions but numeric approximations. Anyway if you are about to solve linear programming (simplex) such as in your example, you should use [linprog](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) function.

Comment: While I agree with you on the distinction generally, Matlab does have symbolic solvers, including Solve. I can use linprog, but it seems like in doing so I'm being computationally wasteful in that I'm asking for a particular solution when I only need an arbitrary one. Really, I only need to know whether one exists or not -- I would think Solve would be better for this.

Comment: @Shane - Take a look at MuPad within MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/solve-algebraic-equations-and-inequalities.html - This more or less mimics the functionality that Mathematica has as a symbolic solver.